# accounting for duplicates in a custom clojure vector

Tags: vector, clojure

I am trying to come up with a functional solution to account for duplicates in a custom data structure that consists of alternating sets and numerical values.

An example:

```
(def a [#{:a} 0.1 #{:b} 0.3 #{:a :b} 0.1 #{:a} 0.3 #{:b} 0.1 #{:a} 0.1])
```

I want to add the values corresponding to duplicate sets to result in

```
[#{:a} 0.5 #{:b} 0.4 #{:a :b} 0.1]
```

I can do this using `loop/recur` but was wondering if there is a way that uses higher-order function in Clojure.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your loop/recur solution?

Comment: Is the order of the pairs significant? If not, you can hold the data as a map from set of keywords to sequence (vector?) of numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would fold the source vector into a map with keys serving as aggregates for numerical values, and then unfold it back into a vector.

```
(->> a
     (partition 2)
     (reduce (fn [acc [k v]]
               (if (get acc k)
                 (update acc k (partial + v))
                 (assoc acc k v)))
             {})
     (reduce (fn [acc [k v]]
               (into acc [k v]))
             []))
```

Answer (score 5):

```
(reduce
  (fn [acc [k v]]
    (update acc k (fnil + 0) v))
  {}
  (partition 2 a))
```

First, partition your sequence into key-value pairs with `partition` and then `reduce` those pairs. The trick is to use `fnil` which will replace `nil` for keys that hasn't been added to `acc` yet with value `0`.

That gives you a map:

```
{#{:a} 0.5, #{:b} 0.4, #{:b :a} 0.1}
```

If you need it as the flat sequence of values you can pass it through `seq` and `flatten`:

```
(->> a
  (partition 2)
  (reduce
    (fn [acc [k v]]
      (update acc k (fnil + 0) v))
    {})
  (apply concat)
  (into []))

;; => (#{:a} 0.5 #{:b} 0.4 #{:b :a} 0.1)
```

Comment: I have never used `fnil` before. Thank you for pointing that out. Very elegant.

Comment: You're welcome :). I have overlooked that you need a sequence of values, not a map. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I know I didn't mark your answer as "accepted" but it is. wish I could mark both as accepted. I did a `(into [] (seq (flatten) ...) ` to get a vector at the end.

Comment: `flatten` is a bad idea in general.. In this case (with just one depth level) it is better to use `(apply concat)` or `(mapcat identity)` instead of `(flatten)`. It would also let you remove the `(seq)` line from there

Comment: @leetwinski you are right, let me enhance my answer.

Answer (score 4):

one more variant (just for fun, because `reduce` version obviously has a better performance):

```
(->> a
     (partition 2)
     (group-by first)
     (map (fn [[k v]] [k (apply + (map second v))]))
     (reduce into []))
```